# Экспорт Jar из Android Studio для Unity3d

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unity3d, gradle

Подобный вопрос уже задавался, но был незаслуженно забыт. Более того, на EnSO есть ответ на этот вопрос, но за 2013 год и сейчас он не работает.

Суть. Надо упаковать несколько классов c сторонней библиотекой в jar, пишем плагин для Unity3D на Android.

Пытались сделать вот так https://habrahabr.ru/post/226987/

Решение с EnSO
Пишем в build.gradle следующий код

```
task clearJar(type: Delete) {
delete 'build/libs/myCompiledLibrary.jar'
}

task makeJar(type: Copy) {
from('build/bundles/release/')
into('build/libs/')
include('classes.jar')
rename ('classes.jar', 'myCompiledLibrary.jar')
}

makeJar.dependsOn(clearJar, build)
```

Потом используем в task gradle нашу задачу MakeJar и он начинает что то делать. Делает примерно 20 секунд, в процессе выдает

```
Executing tasks: [makeJar]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateSigningDebug
:app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:lintVitalRelease
:app:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:packageRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleRelease
:app:assemble
:app:lint
Ran lint on variant release: 7 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 7 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:///C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/Sensors/app/build/outputs/lint-results-debug.html
Wrote XML report to file:///C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/Sensors/app/build/outputs/lint-results-debug.xml
:app:incrementalDebugUnitTestJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugUnitTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugUnitTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleDebugUnitTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:testDebugUnitTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalReleaseUnitTestJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseUnitTestDependencies
:app:compileReleaseUnitTestJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseUnitTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseUnitTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleReleaseUnitTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:testReleaseUnitTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:test UP-TO-DATE
:app:check
:app:build
:app:clearJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:makeJar UP-TO-DATE

    BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

И в итоге в папке libs нет ничего нового - только наша старая библиотека classes, которую мы взяли от Unity. Дата создания старая, не меняется.

Если способ рабочий, то есть предположение - с 2013 года вышло много версий Android Studio, очень сильно поменялась система и возможно мы берем исходные данные для Gradle не оттуда!

Если это так, объясните, как отредактировать код, предоставленный выше, в соответствии с версией Android Studio 2.2.

Если это не так - подскажите, как создать jar- архив из созданных мной классов и внешней jar библиотеки Unity.

Было бы здорово если бы ответ был универсален - т.е. не устаревал, как устарел ответ на этот вопрос на EnSO 2013. Что нибудь вроде - ищем в папке Android Studio такой то файл. Папку, находящуюся в этом файле указываем в Android Studio. Чтобы, как ни менялась внутренняя структура андроид проекта, всегда можно было применить нужный способ.

Добавлено - можно и не из Android Studio. Просто хоть как нибудь создать плагин для Unity, хоть jar, хоть aar, хоть на каком софте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто создаём стандартный проект для Android. Для начала необходимо скопировать classes.jar из директории установки Unity. В проекте создайте папочку libs и киньте туда classes.jar.

Настраиваем **gradle build** скрипт.
Удаляем строчки:

```
applicationId "..."
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
```

Изменяем строчку:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

на:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

добавляем в блок `dependencies {}`

```
// классы, которые мы скопировали из Unity директории
// не включаем их в итоговую сборку, чтоб потом не было конфликтов
provided files('libs/classes.jar')
```

Редактируем **AndroidManifest.xml**
Так же удаляем всё ненужное. В итоге останется что-то такое:

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Сборка AAR**

Чтобы сбилдить проект. Пункт AssembleRelease в меню Gradle. Теперь скопируем полученный aar в /Plugins/Android.

---

Выделил основную информацию из статьи

http://suvitruf.ru/2016/02/17/3893/