# Управление android из Unity, включение вибрации и фонаря

Tags: java, android, c#, unity3d

У Unity нет многих встроенных средств работы с устройствами андроид. 
Но Unity позволяет обращаться напрямую к Java в процессе работы.

Например, для включения вибрации это выглядит так

```
public static class VibratorWrapper
{

static AndroidJavaObject vibrator = null;

static VibratorWrapper()
{

    var unityPlayerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    var unityPlayerActivity = unityPlayerClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    vibrator = unityPlayerActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getSystemService", "vibrator");

}

public static bool HasVibrator()
{
    return vibrator.Call<bool>("hasVibrator");
}

public static void Cancel()
{
    if (HasVibrator()) vibrator.Call("cancel");
}

public static void Vibrate(long time)
{
    if (HasVibrator()) vibrator.Call("vibrate", time);
}
```

И управляющий класс

```
public class VibratorTestGUI : MonoBehaviour
{
 public void OnGUI()
{
    if (GUILayout.Button("Vibrate 2s"))
    {
        VibratorWrapper.Vibrate(2000L);
    }
}
}
```

Теперь сам вопрос - приведённая схема работает, но она слишком простая. В Android это вызывается всё буквально парой строчек

```
Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
vibrator.vibrate(mills);
```

Что делать, если мне надо получить объект у объекта, например, чтобы включить вспышку? На Java это выглядит так

```
Camera cam = Camera.open();     
Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
cam.setParameters(p);
cam.startPreview();
params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF); // Выключили
cam.stopPreview();
cam.release();
```

Или, допустим, снять показания с аккселерометра? 
На андроиде

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager)     getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

sensorManager.registerListener(new SensorEventListener() {
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    float x = event.values[0];
    float y = event.values[1];
    float z = event.values[2];
    double total = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
}

}, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

Т.е. достаточно сложная операция, с Implements и событиями. Как получить данные отсюда?

Полезен будет любой ответ, даже частичный. Хотя бы какая нибудь подсказка на принцип работы

Answer (score 1):

> Как получить данные отсюда?

Данные получаются точно так же как и в первом примере.

В **Java** вы должны написать public методы, которые будут служить связью с unity.
В вашем примере это:

> hasVibrator;
>   cancel;
>   vibrate;

В этих методах вы можете выполнять действия любой сложности.
В **java** коде это примерно выглядит так:

```
public static bool hasVibrator(){
    *какой-то код*
    return hasVibrator;
}
```

Затем, в **С#** коде получаете необходимые классы, объекты и службы.

```
var unityPlayerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    var unityPlayerActivity = unityPlayerClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    vibrator = unityPlayerActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getSystemService", "vibrator");
```

И теперь вы можете обращаться к тем public методам **Java** кода из **C#** кода, в вашем случае делается обертка над этими методами:

```
public static bool HasVibrator()
{
    return vibrator.Call<bool>("hasVibrator");
}
```

То что в кавычках - не что иное, как название **Java** метода.
Получается вы сделали **C#** метод, который выполняет **Java** метод при вызове и возвращает **bool** полученный при выполнение **Java** кода в **C#**.

Comment: Спасибо!
Возможно, я понял вас неправильно, но вы предлагаете что то написать в Java? Тогда это будет отдельный плагин, решение хорошее но я так и не нашёл по нему нормального современного мануала. 

Суть вопроса в том чтобы именно из Unity достать какой нибудь метод, или забрать переменную, спрятанную в классе, который достается из другого класса или сервиса. И, допустим чтобы этот класс был implements какой то другой класс. Вообщем, чуть поглубже, чем просто вызвать метод из класса, лежащего на поверхности. Как это сделать?

Comment: В любом случае нужно будет делать Java плагин специально для работы с Unity. Просто взять и работать с java кодом из c# не получится.
Вот тут подробно рассмотрено подключение и написание Java плагина:
[ссылка](https://habrahabr.ru/post/226987/)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!
В примере выше где используется вибрация нет никаких Java плагинов. Всё работает прямиком из Unity.

По ссылке что вы дали,  уже пробовал. Итог - jar из eclipse под android не компилируется, т.к. ADT более не поддерживается гуглом. На актуальной версии Android Studio тоже не получается - способы,указаные в мануалах, устарели около 2 лет назад. 

Если есть какой нибудь работоспособный мануал, прошу сюда.
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/642417/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-jar-%D0%B8%D0%B7-android-studio-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-unity3d

Comment: В мануале unity написано: Note: Unity expects Java plugins to be built using JDK v1.6. If you are using v1.7, you should include “-source 1.6 -target 1.6” in the command line options to the compiler. Вы учли этот момент?

Comment: А в вашем примере используется Java плагин.
`com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer`
Просто он стандартно зашит в Unity

Comment: Не дошло до source -1.6. 
Поскольку даже не получилось сделать сам jar, поэтому работоспособность плагина проверить не удалось. 

com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer
является лишь связующим звеном и плагины должны наследоваться от него. Изначально там нет никаких методов vibrate, мы добавляем их сами в первом примере, разве нет? 
Мы можем использовать что то глубже чем просто открытый класс, который лежит на поверхности? 

Повторюсь, если знаете точно работающий, шаг за шагом, способ использовать Android классы из Unity, отпишите об этом в вышеуказанной теме. Любой способ.